# The cursor doesn't lock back in FPS Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a FPS Game. So, when I start the game, the cursor is locked and I can not see it.
When I press <kbd>Escape</kbd> key, now, I am able to see the Cursor and I can move it around and interact with it on my screen and I can not control the game camera now. That is fine.  Now, I press <kbd>Escape</kbd> key again, and now, I can resume controlling the camera in game, but I can still see the cursor and I can move the camera in game while making the cursor interact with all the stuff even outside of my game window.

The Code

````
   void Update()
    {
        LockAndUnlockCursor();
        if(Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked)
        {
            LookAround();
        }
    }
    void LockAndUnlockCursor()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if(Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked)
            {
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            }
            else if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.None)
            {
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
                Cursor.visible = false;
               
            }
        }
        
    }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the editor this tends to bug out, you have to constantly set it in Update() by saving them into variables.

```
bool isCursorLocked;

Update() {

if (Input.GetKeyDown(blah)) 
isCursorLocked = !isCursorLocked;

if (isCursorLocked)
{
Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
Cursor.visible = false;
}
else
{
// etc
```

just use variables and always set the cursor lock every Update(). If you don't want this code running always then you could use #if UNITY_EDITOR in a way to only set it every single update for unity editor